# Medical or medicinal?

Tags: differences, plant-physiology

I am not an English native. I am working in the field of medicinal plants. I like to know why we don't use term "medical plants"? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Have you checked dictionary entries for each?

Comment: Actually no :( I'll do it right now.

Comment: Please do--that way you can answer many of your questions yourself, and have a more nuanced question for ELU. Make sure to include any confusion you still have from the entries

Comment: Thank you. I find my maybe answer [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/117614-medical-vs-medicinal.html).

Comment: If you solved your own question, feel free to self-answer

Comment: MySky, and if you don't have solved your own question, feel free to ask on English Language Learners, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Medical' is related to the treatment of illness and injuries.
'Medical examination' is when you get yourself checked out by a doctor to see if your are healthy.

'Medicinal' means related to the medicine.

Answer (score 2):

You could look up the two words in the dictionary, but the main thing is that plants are not primarily medical, but they have healing properties like medicines...that is the meaning of "medicinal".